# Find subfolder with the highest number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with a lot of subfolders, they're named based on a pattern with an iterating number in it for 98% of the folders.

I would like to find the highest number(name of sub folder,maxNumber =??) in it, how to do this?

```
numOfRows = maxFolder- 32020

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
'For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders to slow....
 for pnr  = 32020 to maxFolder
    DoEvents

    Call ProgressBar.setMessage("Updating for .." & pnr, ((i + 1) / (numOfRows + 1)) * 100)
```

Comment: The sub folders in Project are called 32145 and so on, however there are also folder called ABD and so on, I just want to get the highest number , which currently are 33365 so that i can loop from 32020 to this number, however currently i just loop through all folders and check if it is >32020 and has len(foldername)=5

Answer (score 1):

You want to find subfolders with the highest number of what, exactly?  This is probably a good place to get started.

http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/download/

Here is the script.

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
'Dim r As Long
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

    r = 14
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & FileItem.Path & """,""" & "Click Here to Open" & """)"

        r = r + 1   ' next row number
    Next FileItem

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.

    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Finally, form the link above, you can download a sample file, named 'File Manager'; click 'Download Now' to get the file.  That should do what you want.